# Null reference exception in foreach (string var in Request.QueryString)

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I tried to find a solution for this question, but with no success...
I tried to remove .ToString() from Request.QueryString[var] and to add an if control
at the beginning like this

```
if Request.QueryString.HasKeys()) {
  foreach (string var in Request.QueryString)
        {.........
           .............
}
```

but nothing....

The complete code is

```
        string[] array_split_item = new string[] {"<script", "</script>", "‘", "’" };
        int pos = 0;
        string strReq = "";
        foreach (string var in Request.QueryString)
        {
            foreach (string strItem in array_split_item)
            {
                strReq = Request.QueryString[var].ToString();
                pos = strReq.ToLower().IndexOf(strItem.ToLower()) + 1;
                if (pos > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("Some Text");
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Why this exception?

Thanks

Comment: Is `Request.QueryString` null?

Comment: On which line you get the exception?

Answer (score 1):

you can't foreach through Request.QueryString like that.

Try this (not tested)

```
foreach (string KEY in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{

string value = Request.QueryString[KEY]; //already a string by design, no need to ToString() it

// ... use value for whatever you need

}
```

**EDIT:**
visual studio 2008 builds this fine (pasted into the page_load method of an ASPX page to try it); Visual Studio 2010 SP1 doesn't complain either upoon building.

```
string[] array_split_item = new string[] { "<script", "</script>", "‘", "’" };
int pos = 0;
string strReq = "";
foreach (string var in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    foreach (string strItem in array_split_item)
    {
        strReq = Request.QueryString[var].ToString();
        pos = strReq.ToLower().IndexOf(strItem.ToLower()) + 1;
        if (pos > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("Some Text");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

There must be something wrong somewhere else in the code i think.

Comment: i tried also with  foreach (string var in Request.QueryString.Keys) but nothing...

Comment: edited my answer: after fixing the .Keys part, your code seems to build fine.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it may be because you're using the value of a key in QueryString to access a value.
Try changing the line `strReq = Request.QueryString[var].ToString();` to

```
strReq = var.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are naming your string var which is also a type. Replace var with another name.

```
foreach (string text in Request.QueryString.Keys)
.....
strReq = Request.QueryString[text].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried 
 foreach (string dangerKey in Request.QueryString.Keys) 
 {
  strReq = Request.QueryString[dangerKey].ToString();
 ............

but nothing....
I can't understand ....

Comment: visual studio says "Use the New keyword to create the instance."

Comment: I get the exception on the first foreach... foreach (string var in Request.QueryString.Keys) and visual studio says "Use the New keyword to create the instance."

Comment: I get the exception on the first foreach... foreach (string var in Request.QueryString.Keys) and visual studio says "Use the New keyword to create the instance." MSDN says... "Use the New keyword to create the instance.

    You may have tried to use an object without providing an instance of the object. For example, Dim CustomerTable As DataTable should be rewritten as Dim CustomerTable As New DataTable.
"

Comment: I get the exception on the first foreach... foreach (string dangerKey in Request.QueryString.Keys)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Request.QueryString.Keys` to loop on the QueryString:

```
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    string value = Request.QueryString[key];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```